# ERRROR: tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:428] failed to run cuBLAS routine: CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED

Tags: tensorflow

I am running the code in https://github.com/yaushian/Unparalleled-Text-Summarization-using-GAN.

Python 3.7.0
CUDA 10.0.0
CUDNN 7.4
Tensorflow-GPU - 1.14.0

The code is written in TF1 format so I am not upgrading to TF2. All the versions are compatible for Python, TF, CUDA, CUDNN but this error still occured

I have double-checked the versions and checked other sources but can't find any solutions